# Enter an integer, program displays whether odd/even, -1 to terminate

Tags: java, methods

so i need to write a Java application which allows the user to enter an integer value and the application then calls a method called isEven to determine and display whether the value entered is either odd or even. The application should stay running until -1 is entered.

I have managed to do this much but I have ran into a problem

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Enter_Input {

    //create method isEven
    private static void isEven(int[] numbers) {     
        System.out.println( );
    }

    static int number = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number (-1 to quit): ");
        number = input.nextInt();

        while(number > 0) {

        if (number % 2 == 0) {
              System.out.println(number + " is even");
        }//end if statement
        else {
              System.out.println(number + " is odd");
        }//end else statement

        if (number == -1){          
            System.out.println("Program Terminated");
            break;
        }//end if statement
        }//end while loop


    }//end main method

}//end class
```

when i enter a number this is what happens

```
Enter Number (-1 to quit):
2
2 is even
2 is even
2 is even
2 is even
2 is even
etc
```

i want it to look like

```
Enter Number (-1 to quit):
2
2 is even

Enter Number (-1 to quit):
7
7 is odd

Enter Number (-1 to quit):
-1
Program Terminated
```

how do i go about fixing this

and also how do i use the method isEven in the code, i'm only learning how to use java so could someone please guide me in the right direction with this

Comment: You need to ask for the number INSIDE the `while` loop, not outside, otherwise you'll just process the same number each time.

Comment: programming note: use comments when you need to explain the theory behind what your code is doing. Things like "//end if statement" when the statement's only a few lines is just clutter. If you use proper indentation, that while+if block doesn't need any comments, it's immediately obvious which parts do what.

Comment: @DavidWallace did what you said and put the question inside the while loop and now the code won't run, it pops up for 1 sec and then disappears

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I get docked marks if i don't add comments like that even if it is clutter

Comment: @RifferRaffers because you initialize `number` with `0` and you don't update it anymore, then the program reaches `while(number > 0)`. This check returns `false`, therefore the loop will never be entered. Figure out a way to enter the loop at least once. Or use a [`do/while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop.

Comment: Just changing the loop condition to `while(true)` would work, since you're using `break` to exit from it.

Comment: got it working with the do/while, but does anyone know how i could use a method within this as i'm supposed to call a method called isEven to determine and display whether the value entered is odd or even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go! I have used a do-while loop for you to understand the use of that too. You should be easily able to switch it to a while loop if you prefer. Please try and understand the logic here, so you can reproduce it in the future. Assuming you are using Java to learn object-oriented programming, you may want to remove the static keyword from your `isEven()` method and understand the effect it has.

I know you're still learning, but as Mike mentioned, avoid getting into the habit of commenting the way you are here. Write meaningful comments to explain a more high-level view of what you are trying to achieve. (Business value, if you will). Not trying to criticize here, I just hope you find the comments useful :-) Cheers

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Enter_Input {

    //create method isEven
    private static void isEven(int currentNumber) {
        if (currentNumber % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(currentNumber + " is even\n");
            }//end if statement
            else {
                System.out.println(currentNumber + " is odd\n");
        }//        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter number (-1 to quit): ");
            number = input.nextInt();

            if (number == -1) {                
                break;
            }//end if statement
            else  {
                Enter_Input.isEven(number);
            }//end else statement

        } while (number > 0); //end do while loop

        System.out.println("Program Terminated");
    }//end main method

}//end class
```

Comment: You're welcome! Would appreciate if you would mark it as correct if it's what you were looking for :) Cheers